# SSIS SQL Server Datetime conversion issue

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am working on a project that loads CSV files into a table.
The table has a DateCreated field and was reported to have future values, which doesn't make sense in concept.

When analyzing the future values I found that the CSV files are loaded from different sources and some sources send them using the dd/mm/yyyy format and others uses mm/dd/yyyy format.

On the stage table the DateCreated field is datetime so the conversion is implicit.

The problem appears to be with files that uses mm/dd/yyyy format.

When checking one of the CSV file that showed this issue I noticed that there's no future dates, so my assumption would be that all the dates from that file with mm/dd/yyyy format were wrongly converted. That was not the case since only a few of the dates were converted wrong, specifically the December ones.

Have anyone experienced something similar or have any idea on why that's happening?

I tried converting the field but with no success.
I'm trying to fix this issue on the Extract or Transform stage using SSIS or SQL Server.

Comment: it might be better off to clean up the data sources first to ensure that they are consistent rather than having SSIS to consume varying date formats.

Comment: Dates should be conformant with the ISO 8601 standard. You should ask a system of origin that generates csv files of doing that.

Comment: You could use a script transform to TryParse the date string and act on dates in the future but I agree with @BagusTesa and Yitzhak on fixing this issue at the source rather than working around it.

Comment: "Fix the source" would be the best option, but if you are stuck with what you get, I would suggest loading the data into a staging table with the dates loaded as text. You could then calculate the max first component and max second component. If max1 > 12 and max2 <= 12, assume DMY. If max1 <= 12 and max2 > 12, assume MDY. Otherwise, reject the data as ambiguous. You could also add logic that interprets the dates as either DMY or MDY based on the data source or other content in the loaded data, if a pattern can be identified.